# Splitting quantities to fulfill orders - Set based query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to find a set based method to do the following:

Supose I have only one kind of product in my warehouse. This product comes in boxes of different sizes. I have to fulfill the orders using my stock, spliting the containers as needed to achieve the exact ordered quantity. Both orders and stock items have to be processed  FIFO.

As an example, here are some values and the solution (computed by hand).

```
+---------+-------+  +-----------+-------+
| OrderId | OQtty |  | Container | CQtty |
+---------+-------+  +-----------+-------+
|       1 | 87000 |  |         1 | 10000 |
|       2 | 26500 |  |         2 | 10000 |
|       3 | 12000 |  |         3 | 10000 |
|       4 | 43600 |  |         4 | 10000 |
|       5 |  3000 |  |         5 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |         6 |  5000 |
|         |       |  |         7 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |         8 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |         9 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        10 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        11 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        12 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        13 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        14 |  2500 |
|         |       |  |        15 |  2500 |
|         |       |  |        16 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        17 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        18 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        19 | 10000 |
|         |       |  |        20 | 10000 |
+---------+-------+  +-----------+-------+

+---------+-----------+-------+---------+
| OrderId | Container | CQtty | Running |
+---------+-----------+-------+---------+
|       1 |         1 | 10000 |   10000 |
|       1 |         2 | 10000 |   20000 |
|       1 |         3 | 10000 |   30000 |
|       1 |         4 | 10000 |   40000 |
|       1 |         5 | 10000 |   50000 |
|       1 |         6 |  5000 |   55000 |
|       1 |         7 | 10000 |   65000 |
|       1 |         8 | 10000 |   75000 |
|       1 |         9 | 10000 |   85000 |
|       1 |        10 |  2000 |   87000 |
|       2 |        10 |  8000 |    8000 |
|       2 |        11 | 10000 |   18000 |
|       2 |        12 |  8500 |   26500 |
|       3 |        12 |  1500 |    1500 |
|       3 |        13 | 10000 |   11500 |
|       3 |        14 |   500 |   12000 |
|       4 |        14 |  2000 |    2000 |
|       4 |        15 |  2500 |    4500 |
|       4 |        16 | 10000 |   14500 |
|       4 |        17 | 10000 |   24500 |
|       4 |        18 | 10000 |   34500 |
|       4 |        19 |  9100 |   43600 |
|       5 |        19 |   900 |     900 |
|       5 |        20 |  2100 |    3000 |
+---------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

Edit: I forgot to mention this is green field sql server 2012. Thanks

Comment: what is the question ? what have you tried ? Please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: The question is what would be a set based method to get the third table in my post (solution) from the first two? I can solve it with a cursor based, iterative approach, but I'd like to know if this can be done using window functions.

Comment: What is the relationship between orders and containers?  In your example tables, order 1 is matched with containers 1 - 10, but order 2 is only matched with containers 10 - 12.  How is this determined?

Comment: Where did the Running field come from?

Comment: Containers are simply boxes containing the original product as supplied by the vendor. It's my available stock. Once I receive an order, I need to fetch the oldest container available and use it to fulfill the order. Is the quantity remaining in that container is not enough to fulfill the order, then I need to fetch the next oldest one, and thus until the order is completely fulfilled.

Comment: The running field is only an aid column i added in excel so I could explain the process better. It's not required in the solution, but I guess any solution will probably use a similar column to achieve the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  O AS (SELECT *,SUM(OQtty) OVER(ORDER BY OrderId) Ort FROM @Orders),
  C AS (SELECT *,SUM(CQtty) OVER(ORDER BY Container) Crt FROM @Containers)
SELECT
  OrderId, Container, CQtty,
  CASE WHEN Crt < Ort THEN Crt-Ort+OQtty ELSE Oqtty END AS Running
FROM O
INNER JOIN C ON Crt > Ort-OQtty AND Crt < Ort+CQtty
ORDER BY OrderId, Container
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb038/1

This is a Partition Alignment problem.  It's the same type of problem as trying to match the countries of North and South America with the countries of Europe and Africa based on which ones have Atlantic coastlines directly East-West from each other.  The solution should be agnostic to which group is actually East and which group is actually West. All that is needed is this logic:

*If the difference between the latitudes of the southern extremes of two countries is less than the latitudinal 'height' of either country, then they overlap*

Likewise, in this problem the 'containers' and 'orders' are fully interchangeable.  The only thing that matters is the difference between the running totals.  If ABS(Crt - Ort) < MAX(OQtty, CQtty), then that container pairs with that order.

Comment: Hi Anon, Is there a book you can recommend on this kind of problems? I see you used italics in part of your post, and I assume that is a quote from some other text? My real problem is a little more complex than this, so I'd like to read about similar problems. Thanks

Comment: It's not a quote.  That's my original writing.  I don't know of a book for these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using window functions, but it is a bit tricky.  The reason it can be done is because you are counting the total quantity.  In your example, part of container 8 goes to order 1 and part to order 2.  Believe or not, this is much easier than if part of container 8 goes to order 1 . . . and the rest is wasted.

The idea is simple.  Do a cumulative sum on the containers and orders.  Then use a non-equijoin to find the containers used for each order -- this is where the cumulative sums overlaps.  Then do some more finagling to handle the boundaries.  Here is an idea of how to do this:

```
with oq as (
      select o.*,
             sum(oqty) over (order by orderid) - oqty as sumoqty_start,
             sum(oqty) over (order by orderid) as sumoqty_end
      from orders o
     ),
     cq as (
      select c.*,
             sum(cqty) over (order by container) - cty as sumcqty_start, 
             sum(cqty) over (order by container) as sumcqty_end
      from contains c
     ),
     oc as (
      select o.orderid, o.sumoqty_start, o.sumoqty_end,
             c.container, c.sumcqty_start, c.sumcty_end
      from oq join
           cq
           on oc.sumoqty_start < sumcqty_end and
              oc.sumoqty_end > sumcqty_start
     )
select o.orderid, c.containerid,
       ((case when sumcqty_end < sumoqty_end then sumcqty_end else sumoqty_end end) -
        (case when sumcqty_start > sumoqty_start then sumcqty_start else sumoqty_start end)
       ) as OrderContainerAmount
from oc
order by 1, 2;
```

I think this is right.  Without a SQL Fiddle, I'm not able to test it.

Comment: This is pretty much what I had come up with so far, but it fails to dip into container 10 to satisfy order 1.

Comment: @GoatCO . . . I'm pretty sure it will.  Double check the join conditions for your equivalent of `oc`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you very much for this. It's not working I think because of a few typing errors that I already corrected. Also OrderContainerAmount yields 0 for every row. I'm trying to figure out why that is. As soon as I get it I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I think you need an open interval on the join, otherwise when a bag is exactly filled by one order it will still be included in the next order.